# Prove that this theory is incomplete

Tags: model-theory

Given $\Sigma = \{\forall x \forall y \forall z(x \circ (y \circ z) = (x \circ y) \circ z), \forall x (x \circ e = x), \forall x \exists y (x \circ y = e)\}$ (eg. group theory axioms), I need to prove that $Th(\Sigma)$ is incomplete. I know that I can just find a sentence that is true in some, but not all groups. However I have no idea how to go about doing this. Where do I start?

Comment: Hint: are all groups Abelian? are all monoids commutative? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $\varphi$ be rhe sentence $\forall x\forall y(x=y)$. Then $\varphi$ is true in some groups, and $\lnot\varphi$ is true in some groups.

Comment: I think the thing I'm most confused with is how to prove this formally (and how I would go about relating this to $\Sigma$). Do I assign values or?

Comment: (i) You observe that there is a group with one element, for the set with one element $e$ and the obvious multiplication is a group; (ii) You observe that there is a group with more than one element, preferably by explicitly describing one. Together, (i) and (ii) show that there is a group in which our sentence $\varphi$ is true, and one in which it is false. From (ii), $\varphi$ cannot be provable from our axioms. From (i), $\lnot\varphi$ cannot be provable. So the theory is incomplete.